# Trigger to update another table WITH auto-increment value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I'm having trouble creating a trigger for my database.

I Have two tables, lets call them A and AHistory.

**A has an ID and a value.**

I want AHistory to keep track of the value and date for a set time.

**AHistory Has an Auto Incremented ID, the value and a timestamp.**

this is as far as I have gotten:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Atrigger 
   ON  A
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN    
    INSERT INTO AHistory
    SELECT value FROM INSERTED
END
GO
```

Comment: and the question is? You're missing the timestamp? `getdate()` is the answer assuming you're using SQL Server. Or is it another RDBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your db schema looks like

```
CREATE TABLE a
   (id int identity primary key, 
     value varchar(32));

CREATE TABLE ahistory
   (id int identity primary key, 
     aid int, value varchar(32), 
     eventdate datetime);
```

Your trigger might look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER atrigger ON  A
AFTER INSERT AS 
    INSERT INTO ahistory (aid, value, eventdate)
    SELECT id, value, GETDATE() FROM INSERTED;
```

Here is **[SQLFddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd868/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that the ID in A and the ID in AHistory isn't the same.

Comment: In my example **they are not the same**. They both happen to have the same values because they are defined as identity. Therefore please take a look at sqlfiddle and explain what exactly is your problem.